# finding a coefficient to obtain a geometric sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

I have the following:

$$u_0=2 \\
u_{n+1} = \frac{2}{3}(u_n)-n-\frac{8}{3}\\
v_n=u_n + x\cdot n -1$$

I need to find the value of $x$ in order for $v_n$ to be a geometric sequence, which mean that I need to compute the following :
$$\frac{v_{n+1}}{v_n}$$

edit:
thanks for the hints but when i solve the equation it give 2 roots

Comment: Welcome to MSE. What is the question? Yes, you need to compute that fraction. Then you need to choose $x$ such that the ratio does not depend on $n$.

Comment: yes the fraction should be a constant

Comment: @user912835 ok so where are you stuck? Can you calculate $v_2/v_1$?

Comment: (-10/3 +x)/(-65/9 +2*x)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints:

- calculate $u_0,u_1,u_2$
- calculate $v_0,v_1,v_2$
- equate $\dfrac{v_2}{v_1}=\dfrac{v_1}{v_0}$
- solve for $x$
- verify if $\dfrac{v_{n+1}}{v_n}$ is effectively constant for these two values of $x$

**Beware:** $u_1=\frac 23u_0-0-\frac 83=-\frac 43$ and not $-\frac 73$ as you calculated, the index is $n$ when considering $u_{n+1}$.

Answer (score 0):

The hard part is to show that $$ u_{n} = \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n - 3 \, n + 1.$$
The remaining part is
\begin{align}
v_{n} &= u_{n} + x \, n - 1 \\
&= \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n + (x - 3) \, n.
\end{align}

To show the form of $u_{n}$ compute the first few terms to develop a pattern and then check:
\begin{align}
f_{n} &= \frac{2}{3} \, u_{n} - n - \frac{8}{3} \\
&= \frac{2}{3} \, \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^n - 2 \, n + \frac{2}{3} - n - \frac{8}{3} \\
&= \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{n+1} - 3 \, (n+1) + 1 \\
&= u_{n+1}. 
\end{align}
With these components then the desired answer can quickly be obtained.